zgrep command not working correctly on command substitution
I am preparing a script
that will try to detect two texts on the same line. 
This pattern is present in my application log files,
which then further used to identify which file contains the pattern.
Prepared a script like below:
#!/bin/bash

#Takes command line argument#
PROC_CNTL_ID="$1"

#Extracts the file name#
FILE_NAME="$(zgrep -e 'ERROR.*"$PROC_CNTL_ID"' /opt/applications/cds2/logs/intraday/log/*.gz | cut -d '/' -f 8 | cut -d ':' -f 1 | awk "NR==1")"

#copies to pn02398 user specific directory#
cp -r /opt/applications/cds2/logs/intraday/log/"$FILE_NAME" /home/pn02398/logs/

Now my problem is that the script runs with exit status of 0
but still the copy command is not working. 
If I execute zgrep command by giving a specific value
for the command line argument, it also gives the correct filename.
What's wrong with the command substitution?

The variable $PROC_CNTL_ID is not interpreted by bash because of the single quotes

You need to learn to debug better.  Apparently you tried two configurations: (1) command substitution with a variable parameter, and (2) plain, un-redirected execution with a constant parameter.  In other words, you changed two things.   When debugging, you should change only one thing at a time.  If you had tried plain, un-redirected execution with a variable parameter, you would have seen that the command substitution was not the problem.

Since Romeo Ninov’s comment, while accurate, doesn’t provide an answer:
$PROC_CNTL_ID needs to be in double quotes. 
Double quotes that are inside single quotes don’t count. 
So you should do:
… zgrep -e "ERROR.*$PROC_CNTL_ID" …

unless you have some reason to use single quotes.

Many thanks, this helped !
